error consulta sql php
tengo un error en esta consulta y no se que puede ser. Simplemente tengo una tabla con 4 campos y es lo que estoy intentando añadir, con el siguiente error...
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'long) VALUES (?,?,?,?)' at line 1

os dejo mi codigo php, los dos primeros campos son texto y los otros dos decimales
<?php

require ("db.php");

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

try {
    $sql = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO gmdata (user, pass, lat, long) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
    $sql->bind_param('ssdd', $user, $pass, $lat, $long);

    $user = $_POST['fu'];
    $pass = $_POST['fp'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lon = $_POST['long'];

    $sql->execute();
    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $sql->affected_rows);
    die();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


Muy probablemente sea el long, puesto que es una palabra reservada de mariadb (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/). Revisa si puedes poner otro nombre de campo, o si puedes llamar de alguna manera especial a ese campo

El error se debe a que long es una palabra reservada:

MySQL
MariaDB (gracias a @Jakala)

Solución
Escapar la palabra usando ` (backtick), ejemplo:
INSERT INTO gmdata (user, pass, lat, `long`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)


por 3seg mi comentario llegó antes que tú solución

Y, si fuera posible, recomendaría cambiar el nombre  de la columna a lng. Es la convención que se suele usar para la longitud en las coordenadas.
